# Run thin webserver as a windows service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, windows-services, thin

i'm trying to deploy in production Redmine application. I heard that thin is the fastest ruby on rails webserver so I installed it. Now I have a really simple problem: i must start it every time i reboot the machine via cmd because there isn't a prebuilt windows service or something similar that allow me to autostart it. How could i fix the problem? I saw that there is a bat file, so i tried to make a C# windows service like this and it starts correctly but if I stop it the service stops but the webserver is still active and it will never shutdown. The only way to stop thin is to reboot the machine. Maybe I'm wrong, could someone post an example of how should i run thin as a windows service?

Answer (score 5):

i've written [a blogpost](http://www.dixis.com/?p=140) about this a while ago, but most of it should still be applicable. Hope it helps.

But to be honest, i always deploy on windows using the mongrel-service gem, and configure an apache in front to load-balance between 3 mongrels. Much easier. 
Also the big advantage for me was that if something went wrong with `thin`-service, it didn't restart automatically, while the mongrel-service guards your mongrel process, and if it for whatever reason goes down, it will restart it again. For me that was something i could not miss.