# Run thin as webservice Ruby 1.9.3, Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2003, redmine, thin

I'm trying to run a ruby app (redmine) as thin webservice on Windows Server 2003. I've already read and done everything said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370049/run-thin-webserver-as-a-windows-service) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877943/how-to-configure-a-rails-app-redmine-to-run-as-a-service-on-windows), but it still won't work. At the moment I've set:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\[my_service_name]\Parameters]
Application=c:\ruby\bin\ruby.exe
AppDirectory="c:\Program Files\redmine-1.4-test"
AppParameters=c:\ruby\bin\thin start -p 3001 -e development
```

Running thin from command line via:

```
C:\Program Files\redmine-1.4-test>thin start -p 3001 -e development
```

works fine.

I already tested moving Redmine to a path with no spaces, which doesn't change anything.

Any idea what can be wrong? Any hints how I could track the problem down?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running the new service in the account where Ruby is installed - where you can run thin normally from the command line. Edit the service from the Control Panel (services.msc) and [set up the Logon tab](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService) accordingly.